# How to retrieve ID for a CUSTOM CONTROL

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-controls

I have a **Custom Control** registered in the page using this code:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="WebProject.Core" Namespace="WebProject.Core.UserInterfaces.TinyMCE"
    TagPrefix="tinyMCE" %>
```

the Custom Control is placed on page with:

```
<tinyMCE:TextEditor runat="server" ID="uxContentAuthorInput" Mode="Full" />
```

To **FIND** the Control I use:

```
            TextBox myContentAuthor = (TextBox)uxAuthorListDetailsView.FindControl("uxContentAuthorInput");
```

but **DOES NOT WORK**.

- What I am doing wrong?
- Could you provide an example of code?

Thanks for your help

Comment: When you said it does not work, what does not work? What error do you see? Does FindControl return anything? Is the problem the cast to TextBox?

Comment: Is `TextEditor` a `TextBox`??

Comment: It "DOES NOT WORK" because "TextEditor" IS NOT A "TextBox".

Comment: Hello TextEditor is a custom version of TextBox. I do not receive any error, just I cannot find the control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

Add:

```
Using WebProject.Core.UserInterfaces.TinyMCE;
```

And change the control to import the correct type:

```
TextEditor myContentAuthor = (TextEditor)uxAuthorListDetailsView.FindControl("uxContentAuthorInput");
```